# how to reformat this css code to do its opposite?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have a css animation code which makes an object animates as appearing from down to top(when scrolling). Here is the code,

```
 .animate-in-down {
  transition: all 1.3s ease-out;
    position:relative;
  opacity:1;
  top:0px;
  &.out-of-viewport {
    top:40px;
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

I want this code to do the opposite side of what it does now. Which means it should come from top to bottom. Please help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're experiencing now and what you're trying to do. Can you attach more context and a jsfiddle or codepen of how this works now and your expectations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest form of what you're attempting.

Key points:

- You don't need to declare the beginning transition states in your `CSS`, like `opacity: 1`. It's implicit and is redundant to include.
- Don't transition/animate using `top`, but instead, `transform`, as it is going to offer better performance (especially for weaker mobile devices) ([Details](https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/)).

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.box').classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.box.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wrds8gf5/